# Trying to match Excel PERCENTRANK formula in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, scipy

I am trying to use Python to reproduce results I get in Excel.  One of the Excel formulas is a 2 year rolling percent rank.  Data is weekly freq. and i'm looking for the rank of the most recent data point.
The Excel formula looks like this.
`=PERCENTRANK.INC('Indices'!P7:P110,'Indices'!P110, 5)`

Using Excel, I get a value of `.26213`

Using Python, I get a value of `.26923` which is material enough to change values further downstream

Does anyone have an idea how I can match the Excel calculation and results?

This is what i've tried in Python:

```
#python
rollWindow = 104

example = pd.Series([100.0268, 98.6107, 96.8536, 96.9045, 95.7169, 95.0132, 95.716, 95.7043, 95.6948, 96.9666, 97.6367, 97.4099, 96.3846, 95.5558, 95.2478, 94.5487, 95.295, 94.2901, 94.3517, 95.6225, 94.81, 93.915, 91.6883, 91.5727, 91.6745, 90.3186, 89.9786, 88.6776, 86.9716, 85.4051, 86.3174, 86.2327, 87.2157, 85.8357, 87.0657, 86.9309, 84.5083, 84.0628, 81.5965, 81.7031, 79.3157, 80.8909, 80.5395, 81.56, 80.5344, 82.2279, 81.3875, 80.6736, 82.5171, 83.4307, 82.1976, 80.809, 79.7344, 79.5829, 78.7555, 79.2864, 80.4945, 80.0812, 79.9429, 80.97, 82.1083, 82.1985, 83.0025, 82.1122, 83.9145, 84.4257, 82.2824, 81.596, 81.1486, 81.0595, 80.0349, 80.6402, 81.555, 79.7871, 78.9343, 79.3772, 78.0532, 76.942, 75.5564, 74.6491, 74.6702, 73.9801, 73.7626, 72.6968, 73.4371, 72.5184, 73.6416, 72.7711, 73.1224, 75.8298, 75.5966, 73.3623, 73.4183, 74.033, 73.7934, 74.6728, 76.1003, 76.5892, 76.2145, 77.1619, 77.9082, 78.201, 78.1049, 78.2039])
```

'''

Using Pandas.rank I get `.26923`

```
python
def my_rank(x):
   return pd.Series(x).rank(pct=True).iloc[-1]
percentrank = example.rolling(rollWindow).apply(my_rank, raw=False)
```

Trying again, a different way (not really) I get `.26923`

```
python
pctrank = lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(pct=True).iloc[-1]
percentrank3 = example.rolling(window=rollWindow, center=False).apply(pctrank, raw=True)
```

Using SciPy.Stats I get `.2692308`

```
python
def set_rank(x):
    return stats.percentileofscore(x,x[-1])
percentrank = example.rolling(rollWindow).apply(set_rank, raw=True)
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Excel's Percentrank function, but it looks like you could achieve the same result using something like:

```
def percent_rank(pd_series, value, precision):
    return np.round((pd_series < value).astype(int).sum()/(len(pd_series) -1), precision)
```

If you are interested in getting all values at once (i.e. where does each value sit in your range):

```
def percent_rank(pd_series, precision):
    return [np.round((pd_series< value).astype(int).sum()/(len(pd_series) -1), precision) for value in pd_series]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, that was it!  I replaced the function re-ran and it matches perfectly.
Many thanks for sharing your code!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that handles duplicates and values that do not exist in the original array:

```py
def percent_rank(arr, score, sig_digits=8):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    arr = np.round(arr, sig_digits)
    score = np.round(score, sig_digits)
    if score in arr:
        small = (arr < score).sum()
        return small / (len(arr) - 1)
    else:
        if score < arr.min():
            return 0
        elif score > arr.max():
            return 1
        else:
            arr = np.sort(arr)
            position = np.searchsorted(arr, score)
            small = arr[position - 1]
            large = arr[position]
            small_rank = ((arr < score).sum() - 1) / (len(arr) - 1)
            large_rank = ((arr < large).sum()) / (len(arr) - 1)
            step = (score - small) / (large - small)
            rank = small_rank + step * (large_rank - small_rank)
            return rank
```

Examples from [Excel's docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/percentrank-inc-function-149592c9-00c0-49ba-86c1-c1f45b80463a):

| Formula | Description | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =PERCENTRANK.INC(A2:A11,2) | Percent rank of 2 in the range A2:A11 (0.333, because 3 values in the set are smaller than 2, and 6 are larger than 2; 3/(3+6)=0.333). | 0.333 |
| =PERCENTRANK.INC(A2:A11,4) | Percent rank of 4 in the range A2:A11. | 0.555 |
| =PERCENTRANK.INC(A2:A11,8) | Percent rank of 8 in the range A2:A11 | 0.666 |
| =PERCENTRANK.INC(A2:A11,5) | Percent rank of 5 in the range A2:A11 (0.583, one-quarter of the way between the PERCENTRANK.INC of 4 and the PERCENTRANK.INC of 8). | 0.583 |

which matches the output of the function

| Score | Formula | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | percent_rank(arr, 2) | 0.333 |
| 4 | percent_rank(arr, 4) | 0.556 |
| 8 | percent_rank(arr, 8) | 0.667 |
| 5 | percent_rank(arr, 5) | 0.583 |